# Neural Network - how to test that it is implemented properly?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I've implemented the Neural Network using Tensorflow. During the implementation and training, I've found several not-so-trivial bugs.
Example: during the training I had same Mini-Batch loss for different steps/epochs, but different accuracy.

Now the neural network seems to be ready and working properly. I haven't managed to train it well yet, but I am working on it.

Anyway, I would like to check somehow that I haven't done any computational errors there. I am thinking about generating some artificial data for "fake" classification problem with lets say 4 features. The classification should have a very clear human-understandable dependency between the classification output and 4 features. The idea is to try to train the NN on it and see how it performs.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stanford's [c231n](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/#gradcheck) has a couple of general tips for this, like gradient checking.

If you're just learning neural networks, why don't you try to run your implementation on some known data? Many courses provide error and loss curves form models with specified hyperparameters, so you can check whether your implementation's behavior differs significantly from correct implementation.

Comment: I've implemented the NN via Tensorflow. So gradient is actually one line of code: tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, targets=Y, pos_weight=0.1))

Comment: Regarding the data, you are right..Will try to find..But unfortunately most of the basic examples are about image recognition using softmax..
But thanks for a good tip.

Comment: If you just want to check your implementation, so the data you're using shouldn't matter

Comment: OK. will consider it as a an answer and try to go to this direction. Thank you.